# Returning a range from an Offset from another range VBA

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, basic

How can I return a range from an function which includes an offset from another range?

This is my code (Function):

```
Private Function ProcessRange(rng) As Range
    If rng <> "A1" Then
        ProcessRange = Range(rng).Offset(r + 2)  //this is the problem
    Else
        ProcessRange = Range("A1")
    End If
End Function
```

From the example above, I'm trying to replace the range from the offset function. Is it possible?

Comment: What are you doing with your code? Do you know functions and variables?

Comment: the parameter I'm trying to pass in for rng is only a string, A1, B2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- You should define the type of the parameters
- Use `Set` to set the return range
- You havn't defined what `r` is
- `Offset` needs two parameters, rows and columns
- Because you havn't specified a Worksheet, your function will return a Range on the Active Sheet

.

```
Private Function ProcessRange(rng As String) As Range
    If rng <> "A1" Then
        Set ProcessRange = Range(rng).Offset(2, 0) ' To Offset by 2 rows
    Else
        Set ProcessRange = Range("A1")
    End If
End Function
```